# Why this ListBox binding doesn't work two way

Tags: vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I have a view with that code :

```
<ListBox            SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectedValuePath="Tag"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <ListBoxItem Content="Yes" Tag="True" />
                    <ListBoxItem Content="No" Tag="False" />
                </ListBox>
```

and in view Model :

```
Public Property MyProperty As Boolean
        Get
            Return _myProperty1
        End Get
        Set
            If Value = True Then
                _myProperty1 = Value
            Elseif otherCondition 'Let s say that otherCondition is false'
                _myProperty1 = Value
            End If
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(Function() MyProperty)
        End Set
    End Property
```

For this example otherCondition is false and completely independant from this property.
Why am I still able to select No ? (Just visually because in the view model the value stays Yes.)

Precision : 
When I click on Yes, it selects it. But when I click on No, since otherCondition is false, that should let Yes selected. Instead, it selects No even if in the viewModel the value of _myProperty1 remains at True.

Comment: Why do you only have 2 items yet want only one to be accessible?

Comment: The example was a bit over simplified I edited it. Basically, Sometimes the second item is accessible but my problem occurs when it is not.

Comment: Please explain exactly which behaviour you're expecting. Your question doesn't make much sense now.

Comment: I added some precisions, Is it clearer now ?

Comment: The view model can't prevent the view from selecting a ListBox item. You would have to disable the item that shouldn't be selectable. Besides that, a property setter should always accept the passed value. Doing some hidden magic is the wrong approach.

Comment: Ok I understand. But instead of "preventing" I would like to select back the initial value. Correct me if I'm wrong but in a two way approach if I there are changes in the viewModel they should be applied in the view. 
I can't really make the second item unavailable when otherCondition is false because the condition is related to a file being deletable. And I can't check every second if the file is open or not.